# Factory method for Fragment: Setting the class variables vs putting the Bundle as arguments in the Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, factory-pattern

I have been reading about the use of a factory method to get hold of an object of a custom `Fragment` class. Let say I have a custom `Fragment` class as follows:

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

    ..........

    public static CustomFragment getInstance(String message) {
        CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MESSAGE, message);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
   ..............
}
```

What if I have a class variable named MESSAGE and I set its value using the setter on the instantiated object like:

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

    ..........
    private String MESSAGE;

    private void setMessage(String msg) {
        this.MESSAGE = msg;
    }

    public static CustomFragment getInstance(String message) {
        CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
        fragment.setMessage(message);
        return fragment;
    }
   ..............
}
```

Which of the above two is preferred and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which of the above two is preferred

The first one.

> why?

Users will rotate the screen or otherwise trigger your app to undergo a configuration change. Your foreground activity, and its fragments, are destroyed and recreated by default. In your first scenario, the message will be part of the saved instance state `Bundle` and will not be lost. In your second scenario, the message will be lost, unless you add extra code somewhere to specifically hold onto it.

Comment: Won't my class level variable 'MESSAGE' be also a part of the saved instance state because it is the entire `CustomFragment` class object that is being put in the saved state?

Comment: @Swapnil: "Won't my class level variable 'MESSAGE' be also a part of the saved instance state" -- no. "it is the entire CustomFragment class object that is being put in the saved state?" -- that is not possible. The saved instance state of a `Fragment` is a `Bundle`, passed into `onSaveInstanceState()`. The saved instance state of a `Fragment` is not the `Fragment` itself.